# Rest Framework pass additional variables to ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Might seem like a dumb question but trying to pass additional filter variables to a ModelViewSet but request.data is empty.

```
class ObjViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.get('orderBy', None):
            return Obj.objects.all().order_by(self.request.get('orderBy'))
        else:
            return Obj.objects.all()
```

What is the correct way to do this? I don't want to screw up the `/view/<id>/` routing but I also wish to pass a couple more variables via `/view/?orderBy=id&var2=val2`

Using DefaultRouter

```
router.register('objs', views.ObjViewSet, basename="obj")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the `self.request.get('orderBy')` into `self.request.GET.get('orderBy')`

```
class ObjViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Obj.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        order_by = self.request.GET.get('orderBy')
        if order_by is not None:
           return self.queryset.order_by(order_by)
        return self.queryset
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why ```qs.annotate(distance=Distance('coordinates', ref_point))``` triggers ```TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given```?